# Scalpel recovers RAR file but the recovered file is very small in size

Tags: 12.10, data-recovery

I am using scalpel to recover an accidently deleted rar file which is 476 MB in size. I have the following config setting to recover rar files:

```
   rar     n       10000000000000000000        Rar!
```

and running the following command:

```
sudo scalpel /dev/sda1 -o ./recovered/
```

it shows the following result:

```
Scalpel version 1.60
Written by Golden G. Richard III, based on Foremost 0.69.

Opening target "/dev/sda1"

Image file pass 1/2.
/dev/sda1: 100.0% |*********************************************************|  476.0 MB    00:00 ETAAllocating work queues...
Work queues allocation complete. Building carve lists...
Carve lists built.  Workload:
rar with header "\x52\x61\x72\x21" and footer "" --> 1 files
Carving files from image.
Image file pass 2/2.
/dev/sda1: 100.0% |*********************************************************|  476.0 MB    00:00 ETAProcessing of image file complete. Cleaning up...
Done.
```

But when I browse the `recovered` folder as root and check the size of the recovered rar it says it is only 42.1 MB in size. How can I recover the whole RAR file? Please Help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be due to the inability of the recovery software,  `scalpel`. So its a better idea to use other recovery tools like  [r-linux](http://www.r-tt.com/free_linux_recovery/) , photorec

> R-Linux is a free file recovery utility for the Ext2/Ext3/Ext4 FS file system used in the Linux OS and several Unixes.

Which partition is used for storing recovered data from sda1?

## update

It's a bad idea to recover the data to the same partiton. The golden rule is never write to a data lost partition until it is recovered. So boot into a live CD, mount the partition in RO, recover to another storage like a pen drive. If you don't have a external storage and have 1.5+ GB of RAM recover data to RAM. Ubuntu uses RAM for `/tmp`. If you are not sure mount some portition of the RAM at /mnt using `sudo mount -t tmpfs tmpfs /mnt -o size=600M`

Comment: I am using sda1 itself because there is no other partition in my system.

Comment: @SMR that's your biggest issue. When you lose data and want to try to recover it with software your first priority needs to be to shut down the computer and not use the drive. By recovering the data (multiple times, I assume?) and writing it to the same drive you've run the risk of overwriting the thing you're trying to recover. Make sure you use a flash drive or something else to write the recovered file to

Answer (score 2):

You have unfortunately drastically reduced your chances of recovering the file in full by writing to the same partition that the file you are trying to recover is on. Read @totti update and musher comment. The very first thing you should do when attempting data recovery is to cease using the drive that the data is on. I would follow that by making a forensic copy of the drive on another drive or an image, In this way you can work on the copy and insure that you still have the original in an undisrupted condition.